# Build and link a federation server to a community forum?

Tags: federation

Another noob question, thanks in advance for your patience, sorry if not enough specific :

I have a small community forum (a phpbb forum), and i would like to allow members to send test-lumens or test-custom assets between them with their forum accounts.

To achieve that, i think i need a federation server and to link it with my members accounts (with my forum database) ?

Am i right ? Is this possible ? And if yes, any advices to try to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

A federation server would add another level of complexity that is unnecessary imo. Federation servers are for turning stellar account ids into more human-readable addresses. Since your users already have forum accounts you can map their forum accounts to a stellar account id in the user database. Then you can build out an exclusive tool for the forum where people then send tokens around using their forum accounts (eg, people can look up a user on the forum, and when they go to send lumens to that person, the database can do a lookup of username to stellar acct id). then using horizon api requests, once you extrapolate users forum account id to stellar account id, you're working with regular stellar accounts. You can even have users save their unique secret key on their own, to take the responsibility off your end.

As a heads up, using test-net for non-testing situations is discouraged. Testnet gets reset occasionally, so your users would lose their balances and accounts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Any advice about tools for map forum accounts to stellar accounts ?